# Any way to find the lowest possible number from a file

Tags: c++, element

So i have this code right here that looks at a .txt file and finds the highest possible number out of a primary and secondary that are added. But i have no idea how to make it find the smallest possible one. Im supposed to get an output of the smallest number in the file which is 15 but im getting 40 which is simply the first element. There are no inputs.

Contents of the file:

```
+Test1 Test2 30 10
+Test3 Test4 45 5
+Test5 Test6 10 5
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct counter{
    string name;
    string lastname;
    int primary;
    int secondary;
}elements[30];

void Min()
{
    int min = elements[0].primary + elements[0].secondary;
    int total;

    for(int i=1;i>30;i++)
    {
        total=elements[i].primary + elements[i].secondary;

        if(total < min) 
        {
            min=total;
        }

    }
    cout<<"Largest number"<<min<<endl;

}

int main()
{
    ifstream input("Element.txt");
    int i=0;
    while(!input.eof())
    {
        input>> elements[i].name >> elements[i].lastname >> elements[i].primary >> elements[i].secondary;
        i++;
    }

    Min();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212824/discussion-on-question-by-marko-kuzmanovic-any-way-to-find-the-lowest-possible-n).

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all elements in the std::set (container that is declareted in  (`#include <set>`)), than it will be easy to find max and min numbers, it seems to me the easiest way.
Set sort all of it`s element automaticly.
Example of using std::set:

```
#incluse <set>

int main()
{
std::set <int> st; //creating set
st.insert(3);
st.insert(2);
st.insert(88);
for(auto i:st) //for each cycle
std::cout << i << ", ";
}
```

Output will be 2, 3, 88,

*st.begin() will return the fisrt element (min value that you have passed)
Don`t forget to use star before st.begin()

Comment: could you please clarify

Comment: std::set is an container (like vector) with automatic elements sorting, it is defined in set header, to add element in the set use set_name.insert(), to get first element use *set_name.begin(), to get last use *set_name.end()

Comment: I will upvote the answer. It explains very well, how ````int```` values can be put into a ````std::set````

Answer (score 1):

I hope that the guardians of the grail show some mercy and allow me to answer.

Let me first list up the problems that I found while reading:

- Usage of plain C arrays. Do not use C-Style arrays in C++
- Usage of magic number 30. Why 30 and not 35 or 555?
- No constexpr used for magic number. If you change 30 in one place to 35, you will forget it in the other place, which will lead to catastrophy
- `using namespace std;` Never do that. Never.
- `min` must be initialized with maximum int value, so that the first compared value will be smaller.
- `total` should be defined in the loop and as constant. It is not used outside the loop. So you pollute the namespace of outside the loop
- For loop has wrong initial value and wrong condition
- Text hould be: "Smallest Number: "
- Never use `while(!input.eof())`. This is a bug.
- Check, if `i` stays within bounds. The array has only 30 elements. Limit it to that number, otherwise you will get undefined behavior
- You must only check so many elements, as have been read. Otherwise, the unused elements in the array are are always 0 and the result of nin will always be 0.

Please see a updated solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

constexpr unsigned int MaxElements = 30;

struct Counter {
    std::string name{};
    std::string lastname{};
    int primary{};
    int secondary{};
};

Counter elements[MaxElements];

void minTotal(int numberOfElements)
{
    int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        const int total = elements[i].primary + elements[i].secondary;
        if (total < min) {
            min = total;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Smallest number: " << min << '\n';
}
void maxTotal(int numberOfElements)
{
    int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
        const int total = elements[i].primary + elements[i].secondary;
        if (total > max) {
            max = total;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Biggest number: " << max << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("Element.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while (input >> elements[i].name >> elements[i].lastname >> elements[i].primary >> elements[i].secondary)
    {
        i++;
        if (i >= MaxElements) break;
    }
    minTotal(i);
    maxTotal(i);

    return 0;
}
```

Just for interested people I will also show the C++ solution.

We will use the available minmax algorithm to find the answer.

As iterator wwe will use the `std::istream_iterator`. And for that, we overload the extractor operator for the class Counter. Additionally we add the convenience function sum to the struct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct Counter {
    std::string name{};
    std::string lastname{};
    int primary{};
    int secondary{};
    int sum() const { return primary + secondary; }
};

// Read counter from any istream
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream & is, Counter& c) {
    return is >> c.name >> c.lastname >> c.primary >> c.secondary;
}

int main() {

    // Open the file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream input("Element.txt"); input) {

        // Calculate min and max Element
        const auto& [min, max] = std::minmax_element(std::istream_iterator<Counter>(input), {},
            [](const Counter& c1, const Counter& c2) {  return c1.sum() < c2.sum(); });

        // Show result
        std::cout << "\n\nMin: " << min->sum() << "   Max: " << max->sum() << "\n\n";
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error. Could not open source file\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I  hope this helps. If you should have additional questions, then please ask. I am happy to explain everything in more detail.